# Receiver sleep mode RDA5807M

Tags: sleep, functions

Good afternoon guys!
I have a radio receiver connected to an arduino and I want it not to work all the time, but to turn on by the arduino timer for a certain time, and the rest of the time the receiver must be turned off by software.
I have a working sketch that allows you to tune this receiver, and it also allows you to re-tune the receiver (set the volume and frequency) by calling a function.

```
#include <Wire.h>

#define RDA5807M_RANDOM_ACCESS_ADDRESS 0x11
// registers
#define RDA5807M_REG_CONFIG 0x02
#define RDA5807M_REG_TUNING 0x03
#define RDA5807M_REG_VOLUME 0x05
// flags
#define RDA5807M_FLG_DHIZ 0x8000
#define RDA5807M_FLG_DMUTE 0x4000
#define RDA5807M_FLG_BASS 0x1000
#define RDA5807M_FLG_ENABLE word(0x0001)
#define RDA5807M_FLG_TUNE word(0x0010)
//masks
#define RDA5807M_CHAN_MASK 0xFFC0
#define RDA5807M_CHAN_SHIFT 6
#define RDA5807M_VOLUME_MASK word(0x000F)
#define RDA5807M_VOLUME_SHIFT 0
#define RDA5807M_RSSI_MASK 0xFE00
#define RDA5807M_RSSI_SHIFT 9

//uint8_t volume; // 0..15
//uint16_t freq = 1077; // 107.3FM
uint16_t reg02h, reg03h, reg05h, reg0Bh;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Nastroika(1, 4, 1077); // Receiver setting: incl. or off (on, off), volume (0 ... 15), frequency MHz * 10 (107.7 = 1077)
}

void loop() {
  Nastroika(1, 4, 1077);
  delay(5000);
  Nastroika(0, 4, 1077); // Nastroika(0)
  delay(5000);
}

void setRegister(uint8_t reg, const uint16_t value) {
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x11);
  Wire.write(reg);
  Wire.write(highByte(value));
  Wire.write(lowByte(value));
  Wire.endTransmission(true);
}

uint16_t getRegister(uint8_t reg) {
  uint16_t result;
  Wire.beginTransmission(RDA5807M_RANDOM_ACCESS_ADDRESS);
  Wire.write(reg);
  Wire.endTransmission(false);
  Wire.requestFrom(0x11, 2, true);
  result = (uint16_t)Wire.read() << 8;
  result |= Wire.read();
  return result;
}


void Nastroika(byte Key, uint8_t volume, uint16_t freq) // Receiver configuration after power failure
{
  Wire.begin();
  // Регистр 02h - inclusion, settings
  if (Key == 1)
  {
    reg02h = reg02h | RDA5807M_FLG_ENABLE | RDA5807M_FLG_DHIZ | RDA5807M_FLG_DMUTE;
  }
  else if (Key == 0)
  {
    reg02h = reg02h & ~RDA5807M_FLG_ENABLE | RDA5807M_FLG_DHIZ | RDA5807M_FLG_DMUTE;

  }
  setRegister(RDA5807M_REG_CONFIG, reg02h);
  // Регистр 03h - radio station selection
  // After reset in register 03h, the default value is 0
  // Thus BAND = 00 (87..108MHz), STEP = 00 (100kHz). Let's leave them as they are
  reg03h = (freq - 870) << RDA5807M_CHAN_SHIFT; // chan = (freq - band) / space
  setRegister(RDA5807M_REG_TUNING, reg03h | RDA5807M_FLG_TUNE);

  //Register 05h. Set the volume, do not change the rest of the beats
  reg05h = getRegister(RDA5807M_REG_VOLUME); // Reading the current value
  reg05h &= ~RDA5807M_VOLUME_MASK; // Resetting the bits VOLUME
  reg05h |= volume << RDA5807M_VOLUME_SHIFT; // Setting a new volume
  setRegister(RDA5807M_REG_VOLUME, reg05h);
}
```

I need to modify this sketch and add the ability to wake up the receiver and put it into sleep mode. There is "RDA5807M_FLG_ENABLE" here. As I understand it, you need to change it?

*Added later:*

The method of turning off the receiver for a while, suggested in the comments, works.
However, for everything to be correct, when calling the function when the receiver is disconnected, we will send **Nastroika(0, 4, 1077);** that is, when turning off, we still specify the volume and frequency, although these parameters are superfluous here. It would be correct to write simply **Nastroika(0);** , But this cannot be done just like that, because there should be exactly three input arguments for the function, and not one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch off:

```
reg02h = reg02h & ~RDA5807M_FLG_ENABLE;
setRegister(RDA5807M_REG_CONFIG, reg02h);
```

Switch on:

```
reg02h = reg02h | RDA5807M_FLG_ENABLE;
setRegister(RDA5807M_REG_CONFIG, reg02h);
```

**EDIT:** (to answer a comment of Антон)

Nastroika (настройка) means "tuning". Is that right? Then I would use this method only for tuning. Create two methods one for switching off and one for switching on.

```
void switchOff()
{
   reg02h = reg02h & ~RDA5807M_FLG_ENABLE;
   setRegister(RDA5807M_REG_CONFIG, reg02h);
}

void switchOn()
{
   reg02h = reg02h | RDA5807M_FLG_ENABLE;
   setRegister(RDA5807M_REG_CONFIG, reg02h);
}
```

In the `Nastroika` Method you should only perform the tuning and let the module of. If you insist to switch on at the same time you could use your old version.

Example:

```
void Nastroika(uint8_t volume, uint16_t freq) 
{
   // !!!!! This is the wrong place for Wire begin
   // move it to the setup method.
   // Wire.begin();
   reg02h = reg02h | RDA5807M_FLG_DHIZ | RDA5807M_FLG_DMUTE;
   // or if you insist / you want to keep the module be started here
   // reg02h = reg02h | RDA5807M_FLG_ENABLE | RDA5807M_FLG_DHIZ | RDA5807M_FLG_DMUTE;
   setRegister(RDA5807M_REG_CONFIG, reg02h);
   reg03h = (freq - 870) << RDA5807M_CHAN_SHIFT; 
   setRegister(RDA5807M_REG_TUNING, reg03h | RDA5807M_FLG_TUNE);

   reg05h = getRegister(RDA5807M_REG_VOLUME); 
   reg05h &= ~RDA5807M_VOLUME_MASK;
   reg05h |= volume << RDA5807M_VOLUME_SHIFT;
   setRegister(RDA5807M_REG_VOLUME, reg05h);
}
```

Usage:

```
void setup() 
{
   Serial.begin(9600);
   Wire.begin();
   Nastroika(4, 1077); 
}

void loop() 
{
  switchOff();
  delay(5000);
  switchOn();
  delay(5000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the code according to your suggestion. If you can help me get rid of two unnecessary arguments, I will be even more grateful to you

Comment: Thank you, I did everything as you said, everything works, I'm happy. We've also fixed some bugs, thank you!